# Rails migration generate

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, ruby-on-rails-4

How would one manage if there were a lot of migrations file made using `rails g migration`?

For example if I had a file that generate a column for a certain table, I had this but again later down the track I wanted to remove this. This type of adding and removing has been repeated quite a bit due to architectural decisions along the way.

I don't like the way I'm creating migrations file for `every` instance of column (columns) adds and I would like to clean up all my migrations file so they are simple enough.

I understand Migrations are recorded with timestamp with matching file name and in the table to check if they have been already migrated or not. I presume I can delete that specific row in question and also delete the same thing that matches with the file after deleting the column not required.

Is this the best way to go or are there any better examples of this?

Comment: Migration files aren't forever, you are allowed to delete them and I'd encourage you to delete old migrations when they are no longer useful.

Comment: Should I delete the migration rows under `schema_migrations` table aswell?

Comment: You could but stray rows in `schema_migrations` rarely matter.

Comment: OK thanks I'll just delete them if not needed and cancel each others out (same column added then deleted)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is possible to get rid of migrations to reduce the complexity and ensure that things don't get 'out of sync'.

The simplest way is to generate a new, blank migration file.  Copy across the contents of `schema.rb`and then delete all the earlier migrations.

Obviously you would want to ensure that you are using version control (such as Git) and that your database has a backup so you can revert any problems.

I wrote a blog post on the subject here http://www.fmhcc.com.au/ruby/database-migrations-in-rails-and-when-to-start-from-scratch/